# from sklearn.utils import shuffle - DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: dll, scikit-learn, load, shuffle

I cannot load a module from sklearn. The error message says "DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found."

Python version: python == 3.7.5

Sickit-learn version: scikit-learn == 0.21.3

All I did was to run the following one line of code.

```
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\userMe\Anaconda3\envs\environment001\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 76, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "C:\Users\userMe\Anaconda3\envs\environment001\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .utils import _IS_32BIT
  File "C:\Users\userMe\Anaconda3\envs\environment001\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .validation import (as_float_array,
  File "C:\Users\userMe\Anaconda3\envs\environment001\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .fixes import _object_dtype_isnan
  File "C:\Users\userMe\Anaconda3\envs\environment001\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py", line 18, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsqr as sparse_lsqr  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\userMe\Anaconda3\envs\environment001\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\__init__.py", line 116, in <module>
    from .eigen import *
  File "C:\Users\userMe\Anaconda3\envs\environment001\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .arpack import *
  File "C:\Users\userMe\Anaconda3\envs\environment001\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .arpack import *
  File "C:\Users\userMe\Anaconda3\envs\environment001\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\arpack.py", line 45, in <module>
    from . import _arpack
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I also tried to import the sklearn package. It doesn't work too.

```
import sklearn

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\userMe\Anaconda3\envs\environment001\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 76, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "C:\Users\userMe\Anaconda3\envs\environment001\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .utils import _IS_32BIT
  File "C:\Users\userMe\Anaconda3\envs\environment001\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .validation import (as_float_array,
  File "C:\Users\userMe\Anaconda3\envs\environment001\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .fixes import _object_dtype_isnan
  File "C:\Users\userMe\Anaconda3\envs\environment001\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py", line 18, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsqr as sparse_lsqr  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\userMe\Anaconda3\envs\environment001\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\__init__.py", line 116, in <module>
    from .eigen import *
  File "C:\Users\userMe\Anaconda3\envs\environment001\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .arpack import *
  File "C:\Users\userMe\Anaconda3\envs\environment001\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .arpack import *
  File "C:\Users\userMe\Anaconda3\envs\environment001\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\arpack.py", line 45, in <module>
    from . import _arpack
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I switched to python == 3.5.6, sklearn == 0.20.0, and scipy == 1.1.0, then everything works. I am not sure why sklearn doesn't work with python == 3.6 and 3.7, but it shouldn't happen.